# How to integrate gRPC web client to Redux Toolkit RTK query?

Tags: redux-toolkit, grpc-web, rtk-query

Have a problem.
Has someone integrated gRPC web client with Redux-Toolkit RTK query?

Answer (score 1):

You can use libraries that offer you api functions that you have to call with `queryFn` instead of `query`.

```js
...
myQuery: builder.query({
  async queryFn(arg){
    try {
      const result = await myApi.someFunction()
      return { data: result }
    } catch (e) {
      return { error: e }
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Can you recommend a list of any such libraries?

Comment: @ioan I'm just the author or RTK Query, I haven't used grpc on the client-side. I have heard good things about https://github.com/bufbuild/connect-web but cannot vouch for it.